# Toggle popup modal on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having an issue displaying popups with multiple items on the page. Essentially it is a vertical "list" of items down the page. So far I have two. When I click the first one, the first set of information displays correctly, but when I click the second item, it displays the first set of information on the popup.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show popup when you click on the link
  $('.show-popup').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
    $('.overlay-bg').show(); //display your popup
  });

  // hide popup when user clicks on close button
  $('.close-btn').click(function() {
    $('.overlay-bg').hide(); // hide the overlay
  });

  // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
  $('.overlay-bg').click(function() {
    $('.overlay-bg').hide();
  })
  // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
  $('.overlay-content').click(function() {
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.overlay-bg {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  /* fallback */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.overlay-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  left: 30%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10%;
  /* add negative left margin for half the width to center the div */
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<p> <a class="show-popup" href="#">Manual Therapy</a></p>
<div class="overlay-bg">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h2>Manual Therapy</h2>
    <p>FIRST SET OF INFORMATION DISPLAYED HERE</p>
    <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="show-popup" href="#">LIST ITEM 2</a>
<div class="overlay-bg">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h2>Low Level LASER Therapy</h2>
    <p>SECOND SET OF INFORMATION DISPLAYED HERE</p>
    <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: first a tag is wrapped with p tag but not to second a tag. wrap it up!

Comment: Try the custom popup with jquery. You can modify this plugin as per your need. https://learncodeweb.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-custom-popup-form-with-php-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your second anchor inside a `<p>` tag, then you can change:

```
$('.overlay-bg').show();
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().next().show();
```

This will help you to target the `.overlay-bg` according to your clicked `.show-popup` anchor

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmduW/)**

Comment: Thanks so much.  The <p> anchor got deleted when I formatted the code to display on here,  but the script change worked perfectly.  Could you explain why exactly it worked? I'm not that fluent with JS.

Comment: It's because when you used `$('.overlay-bg').show();`. It will hide all `.overlay-bg` inside your DOM, not only the overlay that is trigger by its previous button. So when you use `$(this).parent().next().show();`, it will helps you to target only the overlay that is the next element of your clicked button

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `<a>` **anchors** if you don't navigate. If you need **buttons** - use `<button>` instead.
- Store the popup ID to open inside any button `data-popup` attribute

First a JavaScript solution, then a jQuery implementation for reference:

```js
// Toggle popup on buttons click:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-popup]").forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const elPopup = document.querySelector(elBtn.dataset.popup); // Pass the ID from data-popup attribute
    elPopup.classList.toggle("is-active");
  });
});

// Close popup on "backdrop" click:
document.querySelectorAll(".popup").forEach(elPopup => {
  elPopup.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.closest(".popup-content")) return; // Clicked on popup content. Do nothing
    elPopup.classList.toggle("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0004;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popup.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popup-content {
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-popup="#popup-one">Open popup 1</button>
<button type="button" data-popup="#popup-two">Open popup 2</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup-one">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-one">Close</button>
    <h2>Popup one</h2>
    <p>Lorem one ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores corporis nam earum qui exercitationem sapiente accusantium quas.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup-two">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h2>Popup two</h2>
    <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-two">Close</button>
    <p>Lorem two ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptate aut magnam quibusdam sit, molestiae, numquam beatae totam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery implementation:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  // Toggle popup on buttons click:
  $("[data-popup]").on("click", function() {
    const $popup = $(this.dataset.popup); // Pass the ID from data-popup attribute
    $popup.toggleClass("is-active");
  });

  // Close popup on "backdrop" click:
  $(".popup").on("click", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target === this) {
      $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0004;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popup.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popup-content {
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-popup="#popup-one">Open popup 1</button>
<button type="button" data-popup="#popup-two">Open popup 2</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup-one">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-one">Close</button>
    <h2>Popup one</h2>
    <p>Lorem one ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores corporis nam earum qui exercitationem sapiente accusantium quas.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup-two">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h2>Popup two</h2>
    <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-two">Close</button>
    <p>Lorem two ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam voluptate aut magnam quibusdam sit, molestiae, numquam beatae totam.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a id to link, div and button what you want show.

```
<a class="show-popup" href="#" id="1">Manual Therapy</a></p>
    <div class="overlay-bg" id="div_1">
     <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Manual Therapy</h2>
      <p>FIRST SET OF INFORMATION DISPLAYED HERE</p>
      <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <a class="show-popup" href="#" id="2">LIST ITEM 2</a>
     <div class="overlay-bg" id="div_2">
      <div class="overlay-content">
       <h2>Low Level LASER Therapy</h2>
       <p>SECOND SET OF INFORMATION DISPLAYED HERE</p>
       <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
```

and use $(this) and the id.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// show popup when you click on the link
$('.show-popup').click(function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
$('#div_'+id).show(); //display your popup
});

// hide popup when user clicks on close button
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
$('#div_'+id).hide(); // hide the overlay
});

// hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
$('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
// prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
$('.overlay-content').click(function(){
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```